# is there any way to change the default text editor for textfield django in admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I am working on this project on django,i have this model which have few char fields and a text field. What i want to know is is there anyway i can edit the appearance of the text field in django admin panel so that i can edit what i write in that text field like the one in word press where you get options to make a text bold or insert links and images.
I tried this module called grappelli but it just changes the appearance of my admin panel adding colors and decorative stuffs.

```
class Heading(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())



def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ckeditor

https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

on shell: 
pip install django-ckeditor

on settings.py: 
add 'ckeditor' on INSTALLED_APPS

on models.py:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
class Heading(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField()
```

Comment: In Stack Overflow, link-only anwers are discouraged. Please provide more information.

Comment: attribute error : module django.db.models has no attribute RichTextField.what am i missing here? apart from what you told i addded url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')) to my urlpatterns tuple

Comment: My apology disregard "models.RichTextField()" and change to  RichTextField() instead

Comment: thanks mate ..its working now .i still had to make some changes in settings file to make it work.

Comment: hey mate,sorry to bother you again,this thing is working fine but i can't upload images from this richtextfield editor. .i have an option to upload image there but it asks for image url to be entered there but what i want an option like "browse image" or "drag your image here",is there anyway to do that?or is this what you get in django?help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe that would not be possible. Just think of the ckeditor as a textfield and the options above are created via HTML. So uploading an image similar to upload file input on html to the server is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use **django-summernote**
https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

**step 1**: Install django-summernote

```
pip install django-summernote
```

**step 2**: Add django_summernote to **INSTALLED_APP** in **settings.py**.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_summernote',

    '...',
  ]
```

**step 3**: Add django_summernote.urls to project **urls.py**.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    ...
]
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**step 4**: Give **MEDIA_URL** in your **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

**step 5**: on **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
from .models import Heading

class HeadingAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('content',)

admin.site.register(Heading, HeadingAdmin)
```

**step 6**: Run database migration

```
python manage.py migrate
```